# Detect height change and adjust position of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way you can code javascript to be able to detect the height of your browser and then move a div accordingly to the bottom of that browsers height?

Im wanting to get a footer to stay at the bottom of the page constantly as when I do this with CSS there tends to be a large space of nothing when heading to phone and tablet sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is a fiddle. If you make the browser smaller you will see space beneath the footer http://jsfiddle.net/4RvWY/14/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/default_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/contact_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headerwrap">
                <div class="social">
                    <aside class="socialfade"> <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
 <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
 <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>

                    </aside>
                    <!--close socialfade!-->
                </div>
                <!--close social!-->
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <aside class="logofade">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" />
                        </aside>
                        <!--close logofade-->
                    </div>
                    <!--close logo-->
                </div>
                <!--close header!-->
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul class="menutxt">
                        <aside class="menufade">
                            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>

                            </li>
                        </aside>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--close menu!-->
            </div>
            <!--close headerwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Contact===================================================!-->
            <div class="toptxt">
                <div id="test2">
                    <p class="infotxt">Get in touch...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detailwrap">
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/me2.png">
                    <p class="text">Luke Babich</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/phone.png">
                    <p class="text">+27 72 836 0954</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
                <div class="contact">
                    <img class="move2" class="hover" src="images/mail.png">
                    <p class="text">lukerbab@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
                <!--close contact!-->
            </div>
            <!--close detailwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
            <div class="footerwrap2">
                <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
            </div>
            <!--close footerwrap!-->
        </div>
        <!--close wrapper!-->
    </body>

</html>
```

```
@charset"utf-8";

/*---------------------------- Body and Default ----------------------------*/
 body {
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#171717;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#CCC;
}
a {
    color:#000;
    transition:300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Wrapper ----------------------------*/
 .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
 .header {
    position:relative;
    min-height:180px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right:225px;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #000;
    z-index:200;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    min-width:60px;
    top:4%;
}
.logo img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.social {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:20px;
    top:15px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:500;
}
.social img {
    float:right;
    width:35px;
    display: block;
    padding:0 0 0px 15px;
}
img.move {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);
}
/*---------------------------- Menu ----------------------------*/
 .menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:401;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a {
    color:#CCC;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#900;
}
.menutxt {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8vw;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:300;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer Text ----------------------------*/
 .foottxt {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background:#070707;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding:15px 0;
    font-size:0.7em;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*---------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------- FADERS ---------------------------- ----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------- Logo Fader ----------------------------*/
 .logofade {
    animation: logofadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: logofadein 3s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: logofadein 3s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: logofadein 3s;
    /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes logofadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes logofadein {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes logofadein {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes logofadein {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/*---------------------------- menu Fader ----------------------------*/
 .menufade {
    opacity:0;
    animation: menufadein forwards 3s 1s;
    ;
    -moz-animation: menufadein forwards 3s 1s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: menufadein forwards 3s 1s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: menufadein forwards 3s 1s;
    /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes menufadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes menufadein {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes menufadein {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes menufadein {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/*---------------------------- social Fader ----------------------------*/
 .socialfade {
    opacity:0;
    animation: socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s;
    ;
    -moz-animation: socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: socialfadein forwards 3s 0.5s;
    /* Opera */
}
}
@keyframes socialfadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes socialfadein {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes socialfadein {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes socialfadein {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@charset"utf-8";

/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
 .toptxt {
    margin-top:130px;
    width:100%;
}
/*.contactwrap{
    width:100%;                 change back if cant figure it out
    margin-top:60px;
}*/
 .detailwrap {
    margin-top:100px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* center align .contacts */
}
/* clearfix */
 .detailwrap:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.infotxt {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:400;
}
.contact {
    display: inline-block;
    /* make it possible to use text-align */
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 180px;
    /* avoid 15% being making the contacts less than 115px */
    margin: 4% 1% 10% 0;
}
.contact img {
    width: 90px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*bring back if needed*/
    height: auto;
    /*bring back if needed*/
}
.contact .text {
    top:-15px;
    text-align:center;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.contact:hover .text {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    visibility:visible;
}
img.move2 {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move2:hover {
    -moz-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -o-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    transform: translate(0px, -10px)
}
/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
 .footerwrap2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:501;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}
/*---------------------------- Textfader ----------------------------*/
 #test2 p {
    animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Opera */
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a JavaScript solution?  This CSS doesn't do exactly what you want?  `footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }`

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into a CSS [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) implementation, depending on your needs.

Comment: Well it positions itself exactly at the bottom. Below the previous div. However because there is not as much content on the page there is a lot of space floating beneath, thus the footer doesnt move all the way to the bottom as id like

Comment: @Serlite currently the footer is setup as a sticky footer :)

Comment: Hmmm @factordog, if it's a sticky footer it should stay at the bottom even when there isn't enough content, though. (Try resizing the demo that I linked to.) Can we see your code?

Comment: yea ill link the code. Its 2 different style sheets though.

Comment: @Serlite added a fiddle and code. Sorry that its a bit untidy in the css. But basically .footerwrap2 is the div in question here....I have changed it to absolute to mess around a bit with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS table layout solution. Just add the below style into your stylesheet.

In table layout, by default table row/rows will auto expand to maximum height available of the entire table. And if we set all the containers to `height:100%`, that allows the bottom row to be always stay at the bottom of the page.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.headerwrap, .toptxt, .detailwrap, .footerwrap2 {
    display: table-row;
}
.detailwrap {
    height: 100%; /*push other rows to their minimal height*/
}
```

Note, must remove `.footerwrap2{position:absolute;}` and relevant styles.

Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/4RvWY/17/

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be sufficient here. Did you try `position: absolute; bottom: 0px`? (Dont forget to set `position: relative;` on parent element

Answer (score 0):

The `window.innerHeight` property gives the available window height. That is, the space top to bottom, minus toolbars etc.

Then use `element.style.top = innerHeight value` to set the div to the appropriate position. Minus an amount from the innerHeight value to give some space from the bottom of the window.

Comment: That is, if you REALLY need to set it via JS, instead of the CSS option.

Comment: im quite bad with javascript. How would you apply it to s specific div? as ive just started learning it as i generally try to apply it with CSS...sorry D: Yea ive got it to work sort of with a fixed position. But when its absolute on scale it still seems to leave a gap

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your idea right this should help:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyhjmbfp/) - try to resize window.

Comment: its more or less right, just that the content (footer) doesnt scale with width anymore. But in terms of the height it works correct.

Comment: By removing the positioning it solved the issue more or less. Only becomes a problem around 900px for my work

Comment: .wrapper{width: 100%;} ?

Comment: found the fix. But you got it off to the right start. Thanks for the help man much appreciated! :)